# What database is really fast on write to disk?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, kyotocabinet, hamsterdb

i'm working on a biology software that generates some millions of strings (formed by nucleotide bases, A-G-C-T) of length usually bigger than 30 chars. It was written C.

I need a database to store this data on disk fast enough to don't create a bottleneck slowing the entire software and without consume too much RAM. Moreover, i need it to be completely linked inside my application. I don't want to force my users to install a SQL server or something like that.

I already tried hamsterDB, SQLite, Kyoto Cabinet and MapDB without success. The problem is that i need to insert or update data from database at ~50k operations/sec at least. With some optimizations i got SQLite to be the faster. It reachs 18k operations/sec  (it uses synchronization off, journal_mode off, transactions, ignore_check_constraints on, cache_size of 500.000 and pre-compiled statements).

Each sequence is classified as A or B, and i need to know how many i have of each kind. Right now i'm using the sequence as a key and adding a counter for A types and another for B types. On SQLite databases i'm using columns and commands like these:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO events (main_seq,qnt_A,qnt_B) VALUES (@SEQ,COALESCE((SELECT qnt_A FROM events WHERE main_seq=@SEQ)+1,1),(SELECT qnt_B FROM events WHERE main_seq=@SEQ))
```

This is slower than a simple INSERT INTO, but if the seq already exists on DB i need to just increment one of the columns.

With Kyoto Cabinet i got a really high speed, but it only supports string records and i need to add and update integers to count how many A and B i have.

Do anyone knows another good DB that may satisfy my needs on write speed and flexibility of records?

Comment: [BerkeleyDB?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index-085366.html)

Comment: So I don't know very much about your scenario, so my question might not make any sense... but do you need to immediately write the results to disk into a database?  Would it be faster just to write to disk in your own basic file format... and then have a secondary process that comes along and moves your intermediate files into a database?

Comment: Mike Sherrill, yes BerkeleyDB looks like a option. I prefer something on LGPL or GPL, but i will take a better look on BerkeleyDB.

Comment: Michael Fredrickson, i already tried that. This works to avoid excessive consumption of RAM, but performance drops a lot.

Comment: Unless you need to write immediately, you can batch the INSERTS. For instance, do it after every 1000 records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This BerkeleyDB whitepaper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/learnmore/bdbvssqlite-wp-186779.pdf) says that the theoretical limit is 70,000 transactions per second. Actual performance will be much less, and their theoretical limit is based on some  assumptions that won't hold in your case.  But they still claim that BerkeleyDB is substantially faster than SQLite.

> If you consider that a single BDB writer measures a throughput of
>   about 700 TPS, then the theoretical limit would be 70,000 TPS with 100
>   non-conflicting concurrently executing threads.

Comment: I just implement BerkeleyDB and it is doing great. Without any optimization (even transactions) i'm reaching 70k operations per second.

Answer (score 3):

The following [benchmarks](http://symas.com/mdb/microbench/#sec4)

find [OpenLDAP MDB](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html)

to suit the case submitted, in particular for [large random writes](http://symas.com/mdb/microbench/#sec4)

MDB . **13,215** entries/sec
Kyoto TreeDB .  5,860 entries/sec
LevelDB      .   3,138 entries/sec
SQLite3     .    2,068 entries/sec
BerkeleyDB .    1,952 entries/sec